# how to move focus from one anchor tag to another anchor tag?

Tags: javascript

I am facing some issue while focusing sibling `anchor tags`.I have a parent `DIV` or `wrapper` inside that there are few `DIVs` (one of these divs have `rh02current` class).I want to focus `anchor` tag which is present in that DIV which have `rh02current` class.

Steps to reproduce.

1. Run application which have Two input field .Click on any input field .Then press `TAB`.
2. It goes to next input field.Then. press TAB again
3. It should go to `anchor tag or <a>` which parent have `rh02current` class.Then press TAB
4. It should go to next  (anchor tag) or sibling have same parent having `rh02current` class.
5. I also want to do reset if click again to input field .It follow again same steps

I tried like this

```
     let index = 0;
          document.querySelector('#rc20p3').addEventListener('focusin', (e) => {
             console.log('-fous-')
        if(index < document.querySelector('.rh02current').querySelectorAll('a').length){
          console.log('---fous --');
          document.querySelector('.rh02current').querySelectorAll('a')[index].focus();
          index++
        }
          })
        document.querySelector('#rc20p3').addEventListener('focusout', (e) => {
        console.log('focus out')
        index =0 ;
     });
```

I have two issue in my code.
firstly **focusIn**  fires two times . and focus not go to next `anchor tag`.In my example `hello` anchor tag is present.Also I have tried to `reset` the value focus out it not works

[image]

here is my code
https://codesandbox.io/s/condescending-ride-lej3r?file=/index.html:6148-6681

Comment: Hi, are you open with jquery solution ?

Comment: @swati no sorry i am only using javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can re-assign value when input-box is focus because in your code index value on start is `0` but next time also when you click on `tab` it will remain `0` so only first `a` tag is focus.

***Demo Code*** :

```js
let index = 0;
let flg_first = true;
document.querySelector('#rc20p3').addEventListener('focusin', (e) => {
  //check if active elemnt is there inside rh02..div
  if (document.querySelector('.rh02current').contains(document.activeElement)) {
    if (index < document.querySelector('.rh02current').querySelectorAll('a').length) {
      document.querySelector('.rh02current').querySelectorAll('a')[index].focus();
      index++;

    }
  } else {
    //set first `a` focus 
    document.querySelector('.rh02current').querySelectorAll('a')[0].focus()
    index++;

  }

  if (index > document.querySelector('.rh02current').querySelectorAll('a').length) {
    document.querySelector('.rh02cnav').focus();
    index = 0 //restart from here..
  }
})

//when input is focus ..re assign value
function focusFunction() {
  index = 0
  flg_first = true;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" onfocus="focusFunction()" />
<input type="text" onfocus="focusFunction()" />
<div id="rc20p3" class="rc20panel">
  <div class="rh02panel rh02carousel rh02carouselinit rh02random rh02p3   rh02stopped " data-trackas="rc20:panel3" role="button">
    <div class="rh02w2 rh02-slide1  bgimg rh02noscrim" data-position="0">
      <div class="rh02w3">
        <div class="rh02-pcontent">
          <div class="rh02-logo-md">
            <h2 class="rh02-ttl">Expanding the Possibilities of Hybrid Cloud with Oracle EVP Clay Magouyrk</h2>
            <div class="rh02-cta">
              <div class="obttns">
                <div><a data-lbl="cta-0209-panelx-pn-olive-hybrid-ondemand" href="https://www.oracle.com/events/live/expanding-possibilities-hybrid-cloud/?source=:ow:o:h:feb:::RC_WWMK201212P00001:Cta_0209_OLiveOCIfeb9OnDemandPanel3&amp;intcmp=:ow:o:h:feb:::RC_WWMK201212P00001:Cta_0209_OLiveOCIfeb9OnDemandPanel3">Watch on demand</a></div>
                <div><a data-lbl="cta-0209-panelx-pn-olive-hyrbid-pr-news" href="https://www.oracle.com/news/announcement/oracle-expands-hybrid-cloud-portfolio-with-roving-edge-infrastructure-020921.html?intcmp=OHPpanelx">Oracle Hybrid Cloud news</a></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="rh02w2 rh02-slide2 darktheme bgimg rh02noscrim rh02current " data-position="1" style="">
        <div class="rh02w3">
          <div class="rh02-pcontent">
            <h2 class="rh02-ttl">Oracle ATP recognized in Gartner Critical Capabilities Report</h2>
            <div class="rh02-leadin">
              <p>Oracle ranked highest in all four Use Cases in Gartner “2020 Critical Capabilities for Cloud Database Management Systems for Operational Use Cases” report.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="rh02-cta">
              <div class="obttns">
                <div><a data-lbl="cta-0201-panelx-pn-gart-newcopyandimage-db-crit-caps" href="https://www.oracle.com/database/gartner-dbms.html?intcmp=OHP0201">Read the Gartner report</a></div>
                <div><a data-lbl="cta-0201-panelx-pn-gart-newcopyandimage-db-crit-caps" href="https://www.oracle.com/database/gartner-dbms.html?intcmp=OHP0201">hello</a></div>

              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="rh02w2 rh02-slide3  bgimg   " data-position="2">
        <div class="rh02w3">
          <div class="rh02-pcontent">
            <h2 class="rh02-ttl oserif">From farmer to fork</h2>
            <div class="rh02-leadin">
              <p>Land O’Lakes relies on Oracle Cloud to power its supply chain.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="rh02-leadin">&nbsp;</div>
            <div class="rh02-cta">
              <div class="obttns">
                <div><a data-lbl="cta-0120-panelx-pn-cust-landolakes" href="https://www.oracle.com/customers/land-o-lakes/?intcmp=OHP0120">Learn more</a></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="rh02w2 rh02-slide4 darktheme bgimg rh02noscrim  " data-position="3">
        <div class="rh02w3">
          <div class="rh02-pcontent">
            <h2 class="rh02-ttl rh02-longttl">Try Cloud Free Tier</h2>
            <div class="rh02-leadin">
              <p>Oracle Cloud Free Tier lets anyone build, test, and deploy applications on Oracle Cloud—for free. Sign up once, get access to two free offers.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="rh02-cta">
              <div class="obttns">
                <div><a data-lbl="cta-1030-panelX-free-tier-pn" href="https://www.oracle.com/cloud/free/?source=:ow:o:h:feb::OHPpn1030&amp;intcmp=:ow:o:h:feb::OHPpn1030">Start your trial today</a></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="rh02w2 rh02-slide5 darktheme bgimg rh02noscrim  " data-position="4">
        <div class="rh02w3">
          <div class="rh02-pcontent">
            <h2 class="rh02-ttl rh02-longttl">70,000 people vaccinated in first week</h2>
            <div class="rh02-leadin">
              <p>Oracle builds Health Management Cloud used for COVID-19 clinical trials in U.S.</p>
              <p>Ghana uses the same cloud system to distribute Yellow Fever vaccine</p>
            </div>
            <div class="rh02-cta">
              <div class="obttns">
                <div><a data-lbl="cta-1123-panelx-health-covid-pn" href="https://www.oracle.com/corporate/citizenship/health/?intcmp=OHP1123-pn" title="Learn more">Learn more</a></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <ul class="rh02nav">
        <li><a class="" href="#1" title="View Slide 1"><b>View Slide 1</b></a></li>
        <li><a class="o-hf rh02cnav" href="#2" title="View Slide 2 rh02cnav"><b>View Slide 2</b></a></li>
        <li><a class="o-hf " href="#3" title="View Slide 3"><b>View Slide 3</b></a></li>
        <li><a class="o-hf " href="#4" title="View Slide 4"><b>View Slide 4</b></a></li>
        <li><a class="o-hf " href="#5" title="View Slide 5"><b>View Slide 5</b></a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: I don't want to reset like that .if there is no anchor tag or `index` is greater  andhor tag .I want to move the focus to this element `<li><a class="o-hf rh02cnav" href="#2" title="View Slide 2 rh02cnav"><b>View Slide 2</b></a></li>`
`

Comment: it is very tricky I think .when `anchor tag is` complete then move to anchor tag which have class this `rh02cnav ` .. then where I will reset my condition